# Neolog / prefix for use with bubble+ology

Tags: single-word-requests, latin, neologisms, greek

I want to coin a word that means the study of financial bubbles. After learning that Bubbleology is some kind of metropolitan tea beverage, my immediate hunch of "Bubbleology" lost a great deal of appeal.

https://bubbleology.co.uk

I then tried to brute force the Greek word for bubble onto the suffix ology: fysallídology. This created its own set of problems because the Greek word for bubble is not common knowledge (I merely googled it) and probably no one will no what my neolog means.

I then tried "inflationology" but inflation does not imply bubble characteristics.

Is there any way to create a neolog that means the study of financial bubbles without using Bubbleology while still being intuitive enough to infer the meaning of the word?

Comment: Bubbleology appears to be already in use referring to tea. But the coinage of a new term is off-topic as an opinion-based issue. Financial papers just use the expressions financial/asset bubbles study. https://www.thebalance.com/asset-bubble-causes-examples-and-how-to-protect-yourself-3305908

Comment: You might want to read “Extraordinary Popular Delusions and the Madness of Crowds,”

Comment: How about `crashonomics`?

Answer (score -1):

How about *ecobullescology* (eco = finances, bullesca = bubble, ology = study of)?

Comment: This is not intuitive enough for most to be able to infer the meaning of the word. People would get the _ology_ part, but _eco_ = eco-friendly / ecosystem / ecology / etc., _bulles_ = ?. Maybe I'm just daft.

Comment: The _eco_ in ecology is derived from the Greek word _oikos_, which means house. The _eco_ I am using is the Latin word (_oeconimicis_) for _finances_. It would depend on how you look at it.